# Using GOTOs in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I must make a C program (without using recursively, else, for, while, do {} while and also, the construction with if, must not contain 'return') to find the maximum number from an array.
So here is my code for now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void function()
{
    int i, maximum;
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4};
    maximum = array[0];
    if (array[i] > maximum) 
    {
        maximum = array[i];
    }
    printf("The biggest element from the array is %d\n ", maximum);
}

int main(void) 
{
    functie();
}
```

But I don't know how to read an array without using 'for'. Please help me? I saw something using GOTOs but I don't know how...

Comment: You can use `goto` to create jumps and make the program behave like it has a loop. But beware, https://www.xkcd.com/292/.

Comment: @Haris Using `goto` like that is what makes some programmers think that `goto` is evil. It's certainly not the right way to use it, that's what `for` `do` and `while` are for.

Comment: Just a thing , right now `i` is uninitialized in your code .

Comment: @MartinJames: unfair. For example, it's not uncommon to find questions about having to implement a sort function. Of course everybody is going to suggest "why not use `qsort`" - but *obviously* these are Training questions. In this case, the course could be preparing for assembly programming.

Comment: @MartinJames Think of it this way: the fact that someone doesn't know how to use `goto` in such a way -- it's a good thing, right? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `goto` statements to create loops. An example taken from [here](http://www.go4expert.com/articles/loops-c-goto-t29938/).

```
int i = 0;

firstLoop:
    printf("%d",i);
    i++;
    if(i<10)
        goto firstLoop;
    printf("\nout of first loop");
```

But, using `goto` is a bad practice because it breaks the flow of the program and makes the program harder to read, understand and debug.

Comment: suggest adding "using goto *in this way*" or "*for this purpose*" ... a widely accepted use of `goto` in C code is jumping to some common cleanup / error handling code at the end of a function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the goto statement if you wish like the following :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function()
{
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4};

    int i = 1 , maximum , size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);

    maximum = array[0];

label:
    if (array[i] > maximum) 
    {
        maximum = array[i];
    }
    i++;
    if( i < size )
        goto label;

    printf("The biggest element from the array is %d\n ", maximum);
}

int main(void) 
{
    function();
}
```